# What is the best way to create very custom campaign pages?

Tags: page-template, static-website, custom-content

Currently I am working with company that has very specific campaigns and each one should have its own very custom presentation page. Since its very different from usual WordPress theme design (technically it needs completely separate styling and elements), what would be the best way to do that?

- Should I create custom template for each campaign (filled with static content)?

There are quite a few custom campaigns coming up, so creating template files would just fill up template folder (they be used once, so technically its not reusable template) + it would load all styling and plugins from other designs, which it wont use - performance issues?

- Should I just create separate static html in directory and link to it?

Then again, load all analytics, tracking and other necessary items each compaign does not seem like an option.

What is the solutions or at least wise choice?

PS. going through mail found an example http://www.uxpin.com/bundle.html, notice how design of this page is different from rest of UXPin. My concern would be why load all the stuff from main web engine to this page... ideas?

Comment: When I've had to do things like this, I have used a large amount of custom templates.  If you can find things that are going to be in common, you can have them share a header.php and footer.php, but that's not always possible.  Templates can now be in sub directories within the theme, so that's helpful for organizational purposes.  You can conditionally enqueue the stylesheets and js by checking what [template is being loaded](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/which-template-page-is-being-used?replies=6) or by page id if you will know it in advance.

Comment: Hey,  that's what I am thinking of doing,  but still it seems like lot of redundant work.

Comment: if you made campaigns a custom post type, it would be easy to dequeue everything in one fell swoop. logically, if it's not a bunch of template files, it's going to be a bunch of static html pages, so I don't see how that's any different.

Comment: Why would something load everywhere? Simply only register/enqueue scripts and styles where you need them. And I have to double @Milo on the "bunch of" statement.